# Is restriction of projection a covering map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold of dimension $k$ and $\Gamma \subset X \times X$ be an irreducible analytic subset of dimension $k$. Assume that projection on the second coordinate $\Pi_2|_{\Gamma}$ is surjective. Does there exist (analytic) zariski open subset $\Omega$ of $X$ such that $(\Gamma \cap \Pi_2^{-1}(\Omega), \Omega, \Pi_2)$ is a covering map?

I guess answer is YES but I don’t know how to prove it. Any help or reference is welcome!

Comment: If $X$ is algebraic, this is standard. Arbitrary compact complex manifolds may have too few Zariski open sets, I think.

Comment: @Mohan I see. What if we assume X is Kähler manifold? Will it help?

Comment: What do you mean by a Zariski open subset in this setting? A complement to an analytic subvariety? Do you assume that the analytic subset $\Gamma$ is closed?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Zariski open means complement to an analytic set (analytic sets gives topology as a closed sets). I assume that $\Gamma$ is closed (by definition, analytic set is always closed in the topology of manifold).

Comment: Then the statement you are after will hold for arbitrary complex manifolds $X$, not only for projective ones.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you suggest me some reference for this? Thanks.

Comment: I do not have references but, hopefully, I will write a proof sometime later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use some standard facts about analytic subsets of complex manifolds which could be found for instance in:

*Chirka, E. M.*, Complex analytic sets. Translated from the Russian by R. A. M. Hoksbergen, Mathematics and Its Applications: Soviet Series, 46. Dordrecht etc.: Kluwer Academic Publishers. xix, 372 p. Dfl. 195.00;  (1989). [ZBL0683.32002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0683.32002).

The proof of the claim breaks in several steps:

1. $\Gamma$ contains a nowhere dense analytic subset $S$ such that $Y=\Gamma -S$ is a smooth complex manifold (of dimension $k$).
2. The restriction of $\Pi_2$ to $Y$ is locally biholomorphic away from a nowhere dense analytical subset $Z$. The union $S\cup Z$ is an analytical subset in $X\times X$.
3. The image $\Pi_2(Z\cup S)$ is a proper analytical subset $W\subset X$.
4. The preimage $\Pi_2^{-1}(W)$ is an analytical subset in $X\times X$.
5. The restriction of $\Pi_2$ to $M=Y - \Pi_2^{-1}(W)$ is a proper map (in view of compactness of $X$) which is locally biholomorphic on $M$.
6. The intersection $V=\Pi_2^{-1}(W)\cap \Gamma$ is a proper analytical subset.
7. The restriction of $\Pi_2$ to $M$ is a covering map to its image $\Omega$ (Ehresmann's "Stack of Records" theorem).  The image $\Omega= X- \Pi_2(W)$ is Zariski open and dense (in your terminology) in $X$.

Comment: In 2, $Z$ is analytic subset of $Y$ or $X \times X$? In 7, you have written Zariski open and dense in $X$. Do we need to mention dense since Zariski open set is always dense in both Zariski and manifold topology on $X$?

Comment: @MayureshL For 2, I think $Z$ is defined to be the subset of $Y$ where tangent map $\Pi_{2*}:T_yY\to T_xX$ is not surjective, where $x=\Pi_2(y)$. So $Y$ is a closed analytic subset in $Y$. For 7, actually I want to discuss with you (if you're interested), is Zariski dense the same as analytic dense are the same for for (irreducible) analytic sets? I know this is true for algebraic varieties.

Comment: @AGlearner Let $X$ be a connected manifold and $Z$ be a nonempty Zariski open set (i.e. complement of $Z$ is proper analytic subset of $X$). Then $Z$ is dense in $X$ in Zariski topology as well as manifold topology on $X$. Note that without connectedness assumption on $X$ above statement is not true.